# Указатели на переменные-члены в шаблонных классах

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Составил вот такой минимальный пример:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class Point {
public:
  T x;
  T y;

  static T Point<T>::*arr[2];
};

template <typename T>
T Point<T>::*Point<T>::arr[2] = {
    &Point<T>::x,
    &Point<T>::y,
};

int main() {
  Point<int> p{5, 10};

  auto a = p.arr[0];
  auto b = p.arr[1];

  std::cout << p.*a << std::endl;
  std::cout << p.*b << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Собственно по вопросам:

1. Что это за тип `T Point<T>::*` (я, наприме, не могу привести его к `const void *`)?
2. Взятие указателя на переменную-член доступно только в шаблонах?

Comment: 1) указатель на нестатический член класса 2) оно доступно везде

Comment: (1) Указатель на нестатический член  класса это не абсолютный адрес в памяти, а суть смещение члена класса, относительно указателья на экземпляр класса. Т.е. чтобы получить абсолютный адрес (void*), нужен еще указатель на экземпляр класса. (2) - доступно везде.

Comment: В Си это было `offsetof`. То есть относительный адрес переменной. Чтобы получить физический адрес, нужен ардес самой структуры. `T * address_of_p_x = ((uint8_t*)&p) + offsetof(Point<int>,x);` В плюсах такое уже нельзя.